How customizable is AG Grid?
We are looking into various table frameworks for a web application that we are developing. AG Grid looks very promising, though it is a little unclear how customizable it is. And by customizable I don't mean choosing from all of the many table options that AG Grid provides. I'm more interested in how easy would it be to add our own features and things that AG Grid itself does not provide. I saw the modules way of building an AG Grid, would we be able to easily design our own modules and register them with the AG Grid? Or could we extend the AGGridReact class and/or the AGGridReactProps? Or is there some other way to build on top of AG Grid and add features and functionality that is not available directly from AG Grid?
Thanks.

AG Grid is incredibly customisable and flexible and is designed with this sort of requirement in mind.  AG Grid is also extremely extensible; indeed (full disclosure) we have built a feature-rich commercial extension to AG Grid - called AdapTable (https://docs.adaptabletools.com) which does exactly what you ask in your question.
